# int_least64_t vs int_fast64_t vs int64_t

Tags: c++, int, 64-bit

I'm trying to port my code to 64bit.

I found that C++ provides 64bit integer types, but I'm still confused about it.

First, I found four different 64bit `int`s:

```
int_least64_t
int_fast64_t
int64_t
intmax_t
```

and their unsigned counterparts. I tested them using `sizeof()` and they are 8 byte so they are 64bit.

What's the different between them? What is the meaning of the `least` and `fast` types? What about `intmax_t`?

Comment: Those typedefs are worth knowing about, but are you sure that you're looking at the right problem? "Porting to 64 bit" shouldn't generally require that you change your types. In the best case you just recompile.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Excellent point.  I've updated my answer to address that also.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between intXX_t and int_fastXX_t?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9239558/what-is-the-difference-between-intxx-t-and-int-fastxx-t)

Answer (score 87, accepted):

On your platform, they're all names for the same underlying data type.  On other platforms, they aren't.

`int64_t` is required to be EXACTLY 64 bits.  On architectures with (for example) a 9-bit byte, it won't be available at all.

`int_least64_t` is the smallest data type with at least 64 bits.  If `int64_t` is available, it will be used.  But (for example) with a 9-bit byte machine, this could be 72 bits.

`int_fast64_t` is the data type with at least 64 bits and the best arithmetic performance.  It's there mainly for consistency with `int_fast8_t` and `int_fast16_t`, which on many machines will be 32 bits, not 8 or 16.  In a few more years, there might be an architecture where 128-bit math is faster than 64-bit, but I don't think any exists today.

---

If you're porting an algorithm, you probably want to be using `int_fast32_t`, since it will hold any value your old 32-bit code can handle, but will be 64-bit if that's faster.  If you're converting pointers to integers (why?) then use `intptr_t`.

Comment: "On architectures with (for example) a 9-bit byte, it won't be available at all." Perhaps interesting to mention is that the original POSIX definition of `intN_t` (as an extension to C90) allowed padding, so you could have a 72-bit `int64_t` of which 8 bits are used for padding.

Comment: correct me if i am wrong : about int64_t , if i have a 8bit platform it will defined , and if i have other platform that is not 64bit it will not define , is that OK? ; about int_least64_t : it will define only if i have a 64bit platform at least or big than 64bit platform but if the platform less than 64bit it will not define , is that true and in the last int_fast64_t is the default for example if i have a 64bit platform it will defined as _int64 if i and so on but with condition to be 8bit architecture at least , and thank you .

Comment: @user722528: To have `int64_t`, 64 bits has to be divisible by the basic unit of memory (a byte).  So with 8 bit bytes, it would exist, but also for 16 bit bytes.  Or 4 bit bytes.

Comment: If bytes are 8 bits, it's still possible (even though it's unlikely) that no 64-bit type exists, and in that case, `int64_t` will not be defined. And 4 bit bytes are not allowed; `CHAR_BIT` must be at least 8.

Comment: @BenVoigt +1 for a great answer. I was just wondering though, in theory if you were to pass an `int8_t` to a method which uses the parameter but does not do any arithmetic (e.g. the parameter is used as an array index), would it therefore be better to just pass an `int8_t` rather than an `int_fast8_t` to potentially save the time it takes to copy the extra 24 bits to the stack?

Comment: @PLPiper: I should think passing on the stack is one of the measures they use to decide which is fastest.  And why do you think that use as an array index "does not do any arithmetic"?  I see addition in `*(a + i)`.

Comment: Ah fair enough, I hadn't considered pointer arithmetic, thanks!

Answer (score 16):

`int64_t` has exactly 64 bits. It might not be defined for all platforms.

`int_least64_t` is the smallest type with at least 64 bits.

`int_fast64_t` is the type that's fastest to process, with at least 64 bits.

On a 32 or 64-bit processor, they will all be defined, and will all have 64 bits. On a hypothetical 73-bit processor, `int64_t` won't be defined (since there is no type with exactly 64 bits), and the others will have 73 bits.

Comment: That last paragraph isn't correct, because of the requirements laid out by ISO C11 §7.20.1.1 -- "the `typedef` name `intN_t` designates a signed integer type with width `N`, no padding bits, and a two's complement representation". If the machine doesn't have an appropriate type with two's complement representation, the compiler doesn't have to provide `int64_t`.