# What are "Fast types" for described in stdint.h?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [int_least64_t vs int_fast64_t vs int64_t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9318415/int-least64-t-vs-int-fast64-t-vs-int64-t)

For example, what is the difference between following types and why/when use them?

- `int64_t`
- `int_least64_t`
- `int_fast64_t`

Comment: Did you try `Google` search? What did you find?

Comment: @YePhIcK: yes I Googled but finally I prefer responses given here

Comment: @Destroyica: The link given by YePhIcK *does* answer your question, without others having to type it out again. (Lucky for you if I know the answer, I type first, search second. For you as the one doing the asking, it should be the other way around.)

Comment: @YePhIcK So, funny... Just upvoted your comment, because yeah - obvious. After realizing I came here because it's (now) the first result searching google with "stdint fast".

Comment: Oh, my... 6 years later Google decided that this is the best corner for that question :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`int64_t` is a type of *exactly* 64 bit width, two's complement representation, and no padding bits. Such is useful e.g. for work in binary interfaces; its presence is *optional*, defined only on architectures that *have* an integer type of exactly that width.

`int_least64_t` is the smallest possible type of *at least* 64 bit width, with implementation-defined representation and padding. It might be wider, if exact 64 bit width is unavailable, e.g. for work in algorithmics where you need a specific minimum value range.

`int_fast64_t` is a type of at least 64 bit width. It might be wider if the wider type can be handled more efficiently by the CPU, trading memory footprint for speed.

The first one is very specific, but optional. The other two give the compiler some wiggle room if the underlying hardware is tricky, i.e. you tell the compiler under which conditions you would accept a wider type than requested.

Comment: Perhaps worth noting that `intN_t` must be two's complement and have no padding bits.

Comment: @DanielFischer: ...and being optional, yes. A platform having such types shall define those types, but a platform might not have those types, not defining those types, and still be fully compliant. (I.e., a platform using e.g. one's complement for its short, int, long etc. might not define any of the intN_t types, but still be fully compliant.)

Comment: Good point, the optionality, especially since least and fast are required for the standard widths 8/16/32/64.

Comment: @DanielFischer: It seems two language lawyers have found each other. :-D

Answer (score 1):

They are types designed to hold the bits they say, but optimized for the CPU architecture.

This means that on a 64 bit machine, a fast16_t could be 64 bit in size; it shouldn't be relied upon for real type size, e.g. if you write a structure to disk. Use "normal" types for that.